# What is the significance of the double brackets for the [[prototype]] property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I know that every JavaScript object has an internal property called `[[Prototype]]`. Some implementations allow access to it via a property called `__proto__` while other do not. Is there any special significance of the *brackets* surrounding this property?

Comment: Double brackets usually denote a template.. some script might be replacing [[Prototype]] with the path to the prototype library?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It is an "*internal property*" of the object. From [ECMAScript 8.6.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2):

> This specification uses various internal properties to define the semantics of object values. **These internal properties are not part of the ECMAScript language.** They are defined by this specification purely for expository purposes. An implementation of ECMAScript must behave as if it produced and operated upon internal properties in the manner described here. **The names of internal properties are enclosed in double square brackets [[ ]].**

The statement, "These internal properties are not part of the ECMAScript language," means that internal properties are not identifiers that can be used in actual code -- internal properties are not accessible as members of the objects that contain them. However, they *may* be *made* accessible by particular functions or properties (e.g., some browsers are kind enough let you set and get `[[Prototype]]` through the `__proto__` property, and the ES5 spec allows read-only access through `Object.getPrototypeOf`).

The use of double brackets over single brackets is probably to avoid any possible confusion with actual [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) (i.e., property access).

Answer (score 14):

### [JavaScript [[Prototype]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots)

**The double bracket `[[Prototype]]` is an *internal linkage* that ties one object to another.**

When creating a function, a property object called *prototype* is being created and added to the function's name variable (that we call `constructor`). This object points to, or has an internal-private link to, the native JavaScript Object).

Example:

```js
function Foo () {
    this.name = 'John Doe';
}

// Foo has an object 'property' called prototype 
// prototype was created automatically when we declared the function Foo.
// Now, we can assign properties to it without declaring the prototype object first.
Foo.prototype.myName = function () {
    return 'My name is ' + this.name;
}
```

Now, if we'll create a new object out of `Foo` using the `new` keyword, we basically creating (among other things) a new object that has an internal link to the function's prototype (`Foo`) we discussed earlier:

```js
var obj = new Foo();

obj.__proto__ === Foo.prototype      // true
obj.[[Prototype]] === Foo.prototype  // true
```

as

```js
obj.__proto__ === obj.[[Prototype]]  // true
```

Since `[[Prototype]]` is a private linkage to that function's object, many browsers are providing us with a public linkage instead. That is the `__proto__` (pronounced as dunder proto).

`__proto__` is actually a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) function that belong to the native JavaScript Object and returns the internal-private prototype linkage of whatever the `this` binding is (returns the `[[Prototype]]` of `obj`):

```js
obj.__proto__ === Foo.prototype // true
```

BTW, starting from `ES5`, we can use the `getPrototypeOf` method to get the internal private linkage:

```js
obj.__proto__ === Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) // true
```

**NOTE:** this answer doesn't intend to cover the whole process of creating new objects or new constructors, but to help better understand what is the  `[[Prototype]]` and how it works.

Comment: `obj.[[Prototype]] === Foo.prototype` gives a syntax error: ***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [***. You can't access the internal properties as members. Check also the answer from @apsillers.

Comment: @Wilt, as the header says, [[Prototype]] is an internal linkage and cannot be accessible directly (but it still exists). The browser gives us __proto__ and JS gives us getPrototypeOf to access it. Sorry if it wasn't clear enough in the answer. The comparison is there to prove a concept. Not to be run in the browser console. Hope it make sense

Comment: I understand. I only wanted to make that clear in the comment for others. From your example it looked like this line could be executed in code ;)

Comment: @liorElrom `obj.[[Prototype]] === Foo.prototype` is really confusing, why do you not change it to `obj.__proto__ === Foo.prototype`. This still will be accurate, correct?

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov, I think the reason I choose to demonstrate it using `[[Prototype]]` was the fact that the question is about trying to figure out what's the double brackets are. However, you are correct, they are the same in this case.

Answer (score 9):

The reason it's in brackets is to denote that it's a private property. The brackets themselves are never used in code anywhere.

As you pointed out, some implementation provide access to that private property under `__proto__`, but it's non-standard.

Comment: why the double brackets? A single bracket would have been enough? isn't it ?

Comment: @Geek - single brackets could be confused with array notation. Like I said, these brackets are never present in code.