# syntax to get item from an Promise.All([await fetch(),await fetch()])

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following code:

```
const response = Promise.all([
    await fetch(`http://${location.hostname}${this.config.baseName}/data.php`),
    await fetch(`http://${location.hostname}${this.config.baseName}/data.php?a=3423`)
    ]);
const body = JSON.parse(await response.[[PromiseValue]][1].text());
```

I know the last line's `response.[[PromiseValue]]` is not the proper syntax.  But when I look in Chrome developer tools, I see that [[PromiseValue]] is the property name.

[image]

How do I reference the second element of the promise value array?

**EDIT**
I don't believe my question is related to [What is the significance of the double brackets for the [[prototype]] property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174786/what-is-the-significance-of-the-double-brackets-for-the-prototype-property-i)

I'm asking about HOW to reference the results of a Promise.All.  I'm not asking about the significance of double square brackets.

Comment: This seems weird... What are you trying to do exactly? Why use `await` there I don't understand...

Comment: Try logging `Promise.resolve("anything")` and compare the two.

Comment: What about: `(await response)[1].text()`?

Comment: `[[PromiseValue]]` is not a real property, and you can't get it.  Instead, await the promise to get the value.

Comment: Passing `await` to `Promise.all()` makes no sense.  You need to learn what `await` actually does.

Comment: do you need to wait for the first fetch to finish before starting the second fetch? I see most of the answers (except one so far) assume you can make those requests in "parallel"

Comment: @msanford Thanks for your suggestion, but I explain in my question taht I don't care what hte double brackets mean. I only care about the exact sequence of keyboard characters I must type to get a handle on the results of a Promise.All

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things. First, there is no need to await the arguments to `Promise.all`, since the overall promise will be waiting for them anyway. You can, but it's redundant.

Second, `Promise.all` returns a promise that resolves with an array of the resolved values of it's argument. So your `Promise.all` in this case will return a promise for an array containing two `Response` objects. That means you should await the overall `Promise.all` and not it's arguments.

Finally, there is a `.json()` method available on the response, so you don't have to manually use `JSON.parse` if you don't want to. So:

```
// response will be an array: [resp1, resp2].
const response = await Promise.all([
    fetch(`http://${location.hostname}${this.config.baseName}/data.php`),
    fetch(`http://${location.hostname}${this.config.baseName}/data.php?a=3423`)
]);
const body = await response[1].json();
```

Would suffice. You can also take advantage of some destructuring if you like. So this would work also:

```
const [response1, response2] = await Promise.all([
    fetch(`http://${location.hostname}${this.config.baseName}/data.php`),
    fetch(`http://${location.hostname}${this.config.baseName}/data.php?a=3423`)
]);
const body = await response2.json();
```

Comment: There is a difference if they `await fetch()`.  That will force the `fetch()` calls to be sequential, not run in parallel.  And, if they are run sequential, then there is no need for `Promise.all()` at all.  It is not clear here what the OP actually wants.

Answer (score 1):

ES6 provides interesting way of doing this.

To target the second element, try something like:

```js
const [first, second]= await Promise.all([
  fetch(`http://${location.hostname}${this.config.baseName}/data.php`),
  fetch(`http://${location.hostname}${this.config.baseName}/data.php?a=3423`)
    ]);

const body = JSON.parse(await second.text());
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(await second.text())`? Why not just `await second.json()`?

Comment: This will work if he sets content-type header which is not set here